# Linq GroupBy to switch dimensions

Tags: c#, linq

I have this structure:

```
        var data1 = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
            {
                { 1, new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" } }, 
                { 2, new List<string> { "B", "C" } }
            };
```

and I need to transform it to this structure:

```
        var data2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
            {
                { "A", new List<int> { 1 } }, 
                { "B", new List<int> { 1, 2 } },
                { "C", new List<int> { 1, 2 } }
            };
```

How can I use Linq to do that? Do I use GroupBy?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Do you *definitely* need it to be a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` or just something similar? I'd use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345618.aspx) to flatten, and then [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx):

```
var data2 = data1.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value, (p, v) => new { p.Key, Value = v })
                 .ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
```

Then you can still use it as if it were a dictionary:

```
foreach (var x in data2["B"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints 1 then 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var data2 =
    (from p in data1
     from v in p.Value
     group p by v)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.Key).ToList());
```